# Python regex much slower than php

Tags: php, python, regex

I have the **[following regex:](https://regex101.com/r/yHmNjl/3)**

```
(?i)\b(([a-z]{1,3})[-…] ?)+(\2[a-z]{2,})
```

Which runs fine with PHP on regex101 but when I switch to python it needs x1000 steps and x10 time...

Any idea why / How I could make this regex python friendly?

---

I basically need a regex (that matches exactly what the above-mentioned regex matches) that runs fast in python

Comment: What are the specifications for matching ?

Comment: I doubt the regular expression itself is the issue. More likely this is a question of how the expression is used on that site you use for testing. Also different implementations simply have different efficiencies. The PHP extension is coded in C, I assume the python version is implemented in native python.

Comment: @Rahul Anything that the regex above is matching in PHP. Basically stammered words that start with Letters[dash|…]TheSameLetters[MoreLetters]

Comment: @arkascha My problem is that I'm using it in a python application that runs quite slow because it needs to do some work with regex and I was able to identify this regex as one of the slowest. So I started experimenting on regex101 and was surprised that the PHP implementation has no problem at all.

Comment: @FabianN.: Could you please be more specific and add that in your question ?

Comment: @Rahul see the update, not sure what you mean with more specific, I don't need a regex that matches some problem description, I already have a specific one that matches exactly what it should.

Comment: It is crazy, but `[…-]` seem to be in charge, when I replace it with `\W`, [performance boosts](https://regex101.com/r/79cgHo/1).

Comment: Wow, that's just... The old version used three dots and replaced the three dot char with three real dots. I had the idea to do it the other way around basically replace `\.{2,}` with `…` so that I now only have look for this one char `…` instead of three or more `.` ... With this, I got an overall performance boost from other regexes but apparently, it just kills this one. Any idea why? Maybe something with pythons Unicode strings?

Comment: I am not at all sure what is happening. Once you start expanding the character class, performance decreases.

Comment: It looks like it's faster because it found a match. If you change the input to not have any match it slows down again. o.O Where is that performance increase coming from. One match only means it can't match these characters anymore, that's the same as just making the input 10 characters or so shorter.